# Switch case in where clause (sql server)

Tags: sql-server

I want to use case in sql statement where clause but I have a problem as I want to create a where clause condition on the basis of some value and I want to set a not in clause values on the basis of it

here is the query where am facing an issue

```
WHERE CODE = 'x'  and 
   ID not in (
      case  
        when 'app'='A' then  '570','592'
        when  'Q' then ID 592,90
        else 592,90
      END
```

but its not syntax

Comment: if "app" is a column in table then it should not be in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You could embed it into the SQL where clauses like this:

```
WHERE CODE='x' and (('app' = 'A' AND ID not in ('570', '592')) OR
('app' = 'Q' AND ID not in ('592','90')) OR ('app' != 'A' AND 'app' != 'Q' AND ID not in ('592','90'))
```

Or something like that. Creepy code though, so I'd suggest using different queries for different types of 'app' parameter or create a stored procedure to handle your needs.

Answer (score 1):

As 592 is always part of the set, and the "Q" case is the same as the default, just do like this:

```
where CODE = 'x' and ID not in (592, case app when 'A' then 570 else 90 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you may be trying to combine what should actually be separate statements.

You may want to consider using a test condition (perhaps via a simple IF statement) to determine which specific T-SQL statement to actually execute.

Pseudo Code:

```
IF (/*Conditions are True*/)
BEGIN
    --SQL Statement
END
ELSE IF (/*Some other conditions are True)
BEGIN
    --SQL Statement
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --Failsafe SQL statement
END
```

The logical intent of the code produced will be much easier to understand and maintain going forward.